# I am failing to authenticate users on login in asp.net mvc5 using asp.net identity

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity the moment I place the [authorize] tag on top of the action that redirects me to the user dashboard I am redirected back to the login page. This to me means that something is missing from my asp.net identity as I am unable to authorize any user to access the dashboard unless I remove the authorize tag

**My Home controller for Login**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(UserProfile objUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid /*&& WebSecurity.Login(objUser.UserName.ToString(), objUser.Password )*/)
            {
                using (MarketingDBEntitiesModel db = new MarketingDBEntitiesModel()) 
                {
                    var obj = db.UserProfiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        Session["UserID"] = obj.UserId.ToString();
                        Session["UserName"] = obj.UserName.ToString();
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CurrentUserId"] = Session["UserID"].ToString();                     
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"] = objUser.UserName;
                        //await SignIn(obj.UserId.ToString(), false);
                        return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(objUser);
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult UserDashBoard()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
```

**My Web Config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: What would the users home be : "~/Home/Login"?

Comment: for an authorised user it should redirect to Home/userdashboard

Comment: The configuration settings have to be in a location where the users have access.  Do you really want to have the list of uses in the configuration file?

Comment: I suppose its ok to have it there for testing purposes

Comment: Yes, but users need to have read access to the folder/files; and you have to put the users into the file for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this would fail. Your code is not authorizing a user, you're just setting values to the session and saving them to the web.config.

Take a look at this article, [ASP.NET MVC Authorization and Security](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/thoughts-on-asp-net-mvc-authorization-and-security/).